# Hölder's inequality, a first order linear ODE and Lp-norms

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $r>2$ and let $r*$ be its dual coefficient, i.e., \begin{equation} \frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r*}=1. 
\end{equation}
Let $a>0$ and $T>0$.

Does there exists a continuous, $T$-periodic function $f:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{L^2(0,T)}>\|f-af'\|_{L^{r*}(0,T)}\|f\|_{L^r(0,T)}?
\end{equation}
Here, prime denotes the weak derivative.

Clearly, there can be no such function for $r=2$ by the polarization identity and the orthogonality of $f$ and $f'$.

I would very much appreciate any ideas.